# What's the correct way to say the action of someone playing on a swing?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-request

I'm doing an English assignment and came across the part where I want to tell the time I had an accident on the swing, but can't get my head to think of the correct word to describe the action of playing on the swing,

I've heard of:

- Swinging on a swing
- Swung on a swing
- etc

but they all sound wrong to me.

Comment: It's already in the question title: you had an accident while playing on a swing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "playing on a swing" or "swinging on a swing". "Swung" makes it sound like one person caused the swing to swing, either carrying a second person or not: "George swung me around on a swing." That construction would be correct, in that case.